# How to change a project from Scrum to CMMI in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

We migrated a project from TFS 2015 to VSTS recently as a Scrum project as it was in TFS. But we want the project to be using the CMMI process template.

Now, how can we migrate the existing project from Scrum to CMMI process template?

Comment: In short, you can not change an existing project from Scrum to CMMI.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to MS documentation ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/manage-process#change-the-process-used-by-team-projects)) ...

> You can change the process a team project uses from a system process
>   or inherited process to an inherited process. You can only change team
>   projects to use another process that inherits from the same system
>   process. That is, you can change an Agile-based team project to any
>   process you created from the Agile system process as well as to the
>   Agile process. Whereas, you can't change a Scrum-based team project to
>   an Agile-derived inherited process.

But you could still create a new team project based on CMMI and then move your source code and workitems to that new team project. To move workitems you can export them to Excel, create a new Excel connection to VSTS, that is connected to the new team project, and then copy the workitems and pushing them from the new Excel file into the new project.

Comment: Ah! Good idea. But too many complexity was involved. So modified the scrum model to be almost like CMMI and convinced my bosses to use scrum model itself. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Can you help with some breadcrumbs for how to modify the model?

Comment: found it, Organizational Settings -> Process

Answer (score 2):

You can custom a process when using Hosted XML, the changes made to the process template are then applied to all team projects using that process.

More information: [Customize a process when using Hosted XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/import-process/customize-process)

Comment: This can only be used with the projects which are already using the Hosted XML model whereas this project doesn't. Thanks anyways :)